# Parsing JSON response from Binance public API returns error

Tags: json, api, parsing

I believe I don't need to be using an API key to do this:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price",{muteHttpExceptions: true});
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var rate1 = json["171"].price;
```

It gives me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

At first, make sure that you getting data.
After that, try to use json[171].price instead of json["171"].price

Comment: When a key is a number, you have to enclose it in quotes.

Comment: Yes, but your request response is the following: 

```[
{"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.06625400"},{"symbol":"LTCBTC","price":"0.00459500"}
.....
}
```
You can't use a key, for the array.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you show me the working solution. How do I get the price value for a specific key?

Comment: You should iterate over the Array, check each kay by using the IF operator, and choose the price value when the IF condition is true.

Try to write code yourself. I don't want any vote, I just want to help you :)

Comment: I tried this but not working (Am I close?): var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); let priceData = []; for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { priceData.push(json[i].price) }; var rate1 = priceData[171];

Comment: try this one. **Replace "Replace with your key" string with your key**

``` 
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
var final_price = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     if (json[i]. symbol === "Replace with you key") {
            final_price = json[i].price;
            break;
      } 
}; 

console.log(final_price); ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233654/discussion-between-taron-qalashyan-and-rowdogsa).